# PHP script called from within AngularJS service does not work

Tags: php, angularjs

I've made a simple PHP script to update a mysql database. When I run this script as a standalone script, it works as expected. However when I call this script from within an AngularJS Service it does not do the job.

This is my script:

```
<?php
include('../connection/connection.php');
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

date_default_timezone_set('CET');

$cursist_id  = $data->cursist_id;
$id_ggv     = $data->id_ggv;
$cursist_id = intval($cursist_id+1);
$id_ggv     = intval($id_ggv+1);

try {
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $q = "  UPDATE crskrt_ggv
            SET cursist_id = '$cursist_id'
            WHERE id_ggv ='$id_ggv' ";

    $db->exec($q);

    //echo json_encode($id);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $q . '</br>' . $e->getMessage();
}

echo "cursist_id: ". $cursist_id;
echo "id_ggv: " . $id_ggv;
echo $q;
```

When I check the network tab in the developers console, I can see that the right variables are returned. However, the database is not updated.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Does it return the error message ?

Comment: No I don't get any error message.

Comment: your also returning the complete query, try to copy that one and run in manually in your sql console. It should probably return an error

Comment: The sql code in the console works perfectly. I discovered what I did wrong: In the service I was chaining $http requests not in the right way. As a result I got the wrong ID's. Now that I have coded my service in the right way, the php script runs as it should be.
Thanks for your help anyway.